# How to split large csv files into 125MB-1000MB small csv files dynamically using split command in UNIX

Tags: python, shell, csv, unix, bigdata

- I am trying to split large csv files to small csv files which is
  having 125MB to 1GB. split command will work if we give number of
  records per file it will split but i want get that row count
  dynamically on basis of file size.  if the file size is 20GB then
  while laoding this whole file into redshift table using copy command
  but this is taking lot of time, so if we chunk the 20GB file into
  mentioned size files so i will get good results.
- Example 20GB file we can split 6_000_000 records per file so in that way the chunk file size
  will be around 125mb, in that way i want that 600_000 row count
  dynamically depends on size

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details how exactly the number of records shall depend on the file size and why.

Comment: @Bodo I edidted the quetion now can you please check

Comment: Please format your text a bit to make it easier to read. Is your requirement to split your file into blocks of not more than 125 MB while making sure that it is split at line terminations? Or do you expect to get a specific number of files? Make this clear in the question. If you have GNU `split` you could try `split -C 125M ...`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is still unclear from the question how the size or record count of the chunks depends on the size or record count of the large file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the file size in MB and divide by some ideal size that you need to predetermine (for my example I picked your minimum of 125MB), and that will give you the number of chunks.

You then get the row count (`wc -l`, assuming your CSV has no line breaks inside a cell) and divide that by the number of chunks to give your rows per chunk.

Rows per chunk is your "lines per chunk" count that you can finally pass to `split`.

Because we are doing division which will most likely result in a remainder, you'll probably get an extra file with a relatively few amount of these remainder rows (which you can see in the example).

Here's how I coded this up.  I'm using shellcheck, so I think this is pretty POSIX compliant:

```bash
csvFile=$1

maxSizeMB=125

rm -f chunked_*

fSizeMB=$(du -ms "$csvFile" | cut -f1)
echo "File size is $fSizeMB, max size per new file is $maxSizeMB"

nChunks=$(( fSizeMB / maxSizeMB ))
echo "Want $nChunks chunks"

nRows=$(wc -l "$csvFile" | cut -d' ' -f2)
echo "File row count is $nRows"

nRowsPerChunk=$(( nRows / nChunks ))
echo "Need $nChunks files at around $nRowsPerChunk rows per file (plus one more file, maybe, for remainder)"


split -d -a 4 -l $nRowsPerChunk "$csvFile" "chunked_"


echo "Row (line) counts per file:"
wc -l chunked_00*

echo
echo "Size (MB) per file:"
du -ms chunked_00*
```

I created a mock CSV with 60_000_000 rows that is about 5GB:

```
ll -h gen_60000000x11.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 zyoung  staff   4.7G Jun 24 15:21 gen_60000000x11.csv
```

When I ran that script I got this output:

```
./main.sh gen_60000000x11.csv
File size is 4801MB, max size per new file is 125MB
Want 38 chunks
File row count is 60000000
Need 38 files at around 1578947 rows per file (plus one more file, maybe, for remainder)
Row (line) counts per file:
 1578947 chunked_0000
 1578947 chunked_0001
 1578947 chunked_0002
 ...
 1578947 chunked_0036
 1578947 chunked_0037
      14 chunked_0038
 60000000 total

Size (MB) per file:
129     chunked_0000
129     chunked_0001
129     chunked_0002
...
129     chunked_0036
129     chunked_0037
1       chunked_0038
```